# How to connect a Springboot app to an Azure SB with multiple subscriptions (with same name) across different topics

Tags: spring-boot, jms, azureservicebus

I have a Controller in a Springboot app connecting to an Azure Service Bus using JMSListeners.

```
Method 1:

@JmsListener(destination = "${topicX}", containerFactory = "topicJmsListenerContainerFactory",
            subscription = "${XXX}")

Method 2:

@JmsListener(destination = "${topicY}", containerFactory = "topicJmsListenerContainerFactory",
        subscription = "${XXX}")
```

As you can see, the topic names are different, but subscription name is the same.

I get an error in the Springboot app as it's starting up.

Here's the error:

> Caused by: javax.jms.JMSRuntimeException: A non-shared durable
> subscription is already active with name 'XXX'.

I am new to Azure SB and topics, so I am not sure if this is something that is even possible to do? Or are multiple subscriptions under different topics not supposed to be named the same?

This is some code I've inherited to debug and find out what the solution might be, so I don't have much details as to why it was done this way. If you need any more information, I am happy to share.

Please help!

I've tried by commenting out 1 of the methods and confirmed it's working.

I want to understand if there is a way to run both methods without errors.

- ***Edit 24/01/2023*** - I'm still stuck with this. I haven't found much documentation around this either. Most of the online tutorials talk about connecting to different subscriptions with different names, so I haven't come across anything similar to my problem. I don't know at this point whether this is in fact possible or it's a limitation of how JMS works?

Comment: I've posted an answer on the corresponding MS Q&A post you made: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1162597/how-to-connect-a-springboot-app-to-an-azure-sb-wit

Answer (score 0):

- As far as I know every subscription is distinct in a Service Bus Namespace.
- Here I was trying to create a new subscription in a different topic while a subscription by the name `Subscription` already existed in some other topic the portal gave me the following error

[image]

- So I the only way to get message is with distinct subscriptions using the following code:

```
@Component  
public class TopicReceiveController {  
    private static final String TOPIC_NAME1 = "test";  
 private static final String TOPIC_NAME2 = "newtest";  
 private static final String SUBSCRIPTION_NAME1 = "Subscription";  
 private static final String SUBSCRIPTION_NAME2 = "Subscription2";  
  
 private final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(TopicReceiveController.class);  
  
  @JmsListener(destination = TOPIC_NAME1, containerFactory = "topicJmsListenerContainerFactory",  
  subscription = SUBSCRIPTION_NAME1)  
    public void receiveMessage(String Name) {  
        logger.info("Received message: {}", Name);  
  }  
  
    @JmsListener(destination = TOPIC_NAME2, containerFactory = "topicJmsListenerContainerFactory",  
  subscription = SUBSCRIPTION_NAME2)  
    public void receiveMessageNewTopic(String Name) {  
        logger.info("Received message: {}", Name);  
  }  
}
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your response. My case is that there are already existing subscriptions with the same name across different topics and I am trying to read from those. Also this morning, I tried creating a couple of test topics with same subscription names and it seemed to create it.

Comment: However, when I tried to create duplicate subscriptions WITHIN the same topic, I got the same error you mentioned.